# Check if two vars in an multidimensional array match in the same array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array that looks something like this:

```php
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["rowid"]=>
    int(3)
    ["columnid"]=>
    int(5)
    ["seattype"]=>
    int(10)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["rowid"]=>
    int(3)
    ["columnid"]=>
    int(6)
    ["seattype"]=>
    int(10)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["rowid"]=>
    int(3)
    ["columnid"]=>
    int(7)
    ["seattype"]=>
    int(10)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["rowid"]=>
    int(3)
    ["columnid"]=>
    int(8)
    ["seattype"]=>
    int(10)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    ["rowid"]=>
    int(3)
    ["columnid"]=>
    int(9)
    ["seattype"]=>
    int(10)
  }
}
```

The array is called `SeatDec`.
Now I have two pre-loops, they are interleaved:

```php
for ($i = 0; $i < $seatplan->rowcount; $i++){
  echo '<tr>';
    for($j = 0; $j < $seatplan->columncount; $j++){
      echo '<td>ttt</td>';
    }
  </tr>
}
```

Now I want to check with every purchase of j if the combination of i => rowid and j=> columnid exists at the same time and if so I want to get the seattype.

```
$seattype = in_array($i,$J) .
```

Here it hangs with me, is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways can be:

```
// reindex your seatDec array.
// Key will be a combination of `rowid-columnid` and value will be `seattype`:
$SeatDec = [....];
$newSeatDec = [];
foreach ($SeatDec as $item) {
    $newSeatDec[$item['rowid'] . '-' . $item['columnid']] = $item['seattype']
}

// now iterate and check if `$i-$j` key isset in `$newSeatDec`
for ($i = 0; $i < $seatplan->rowcount; $i++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    for($j = 0; $j < $seatplan->columncount; $j++) {?>
        echo '<td>' . ($newSeatDec[$i . '-' . $j] ?? '-' ) . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```